# Does Native HTML have a ListBox element

Tags: html, css, listbox

**Does native HTML have a listbox element? You know how it has a drop box element (called select), does it also have a listbox?**

*If not, do you know how I could place a list box in my Website.*

One method, is to create a table & have each  element detect the onclick event. But I dont want to make my own just yet. Are javascript widgets easy to use?

Comment: If you know `select` and it is not what you mean with *listbox*, what is do you mean by *listbox* then? How does a listbox look like?

Answer (score 3):

Use a select list:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="2">
<option value="Whatever">One</option>
<option value="Other">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The XHTML value of `multiple` is `multiple`, as in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

@Myles has the select box which is correct, you can also allow multiple select options.

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `multiple` attribute to a normal `<select>` and use the `size` attribute to determine how many rows you want shown. (If you don't set the `size` attribute, then all options will be visible.):

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="5">
```

[**See example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/McsPJ/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the select tag, but set the selects attributes of multiple and size.  Here is a reference http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp.

```
<select multiple='multiple' size='3'>
  <option value='o1'>Red</option>
  <option value='o2'>Green</option>
  <option value='o3'>Blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Read here: http://w3fools.com/ A far better reference is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select

Comment: @Šime Vidas Thanks for the heads up.  I haven't had a whole lot of problems with the information from w3schools, though I have noticed that it is lacking on a lot of the HTML5 features.  I will say I like how they have organized the material.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment the standards do not have a listbox element.

There's a web spec in progress about the `<selectmenu>` element which does have a `listbox` slot (not element). Possibly this could end up being back in the `<select>` element

If you want to read more about it:

- https://open-ui.org/prototypes/selectmenu
- https://css-tricks.com/the-selectmenu-element/